# How do we create array of string arrays in vba?

Tags: vba

```
Dim a(10) as string 
Dim b(10) as string 
Dim c(10) as string 

Dim d(10) as String

d= Array(a,b,c)
```

This isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close in your example. All you need to do is to declare "d" as Variant and not as String-array, because it isnt:

```
Private Sub arraytest()
    Dim a(10) As String
    Dim b(10) As String
    Dim c(10) As String
    a(0) = "test"

    Dim arrD As Variant 'Dimensionless variable to hold the result of "Array-Function"
    arrD = Array(a, b, c)

    Debug.Print arrD(0)(0)
End Sub
```

Think of "Array" as a function building an Array-Object with all the correct dimensions and properties. All you need is something to hold that (a Variant), whatever it really becomes.

Note that contrary to normal multi-dimensional arrays, you access the values via `(x)(y)` and not `(x,y)`.